# Single mysql query

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, sum

I want single mysql query to add a new row as total with values of sum of all column values to the following query. please help me

```
SELECT username,enddt,SUM(zerotothirty) AS 0To30,
SUM(thirtytosixty) AS 31To60,SUM(sixtytoonetwenty) AS 61To120,
SUM(onetwentytotwoforty) AS 121To240,SUM(greaterthantwoforty) AS '>240' 
FROM 
(SELECT username,DATE(enddt) AS enddt,tickid,
 IF(duration <=30, 1,0) zerotothirty,
 IF(duration BETWEEN 31 AND 60, 1,0) thirtytosixty,
 IF(duration BETWEEN 61 AND 120,1,0) sixtytoonetwenty,
 IF(duration BETWEEN 121 AND 240,1,0) onetwentytotwoforty,
 IF(duration >240,1,0) greaterthantwoforty
 FROM report)AS r
 GROUP BY username,DATE(enddt);
```

Comment: post your create table command

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier to `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY username,DATE(enddt) WITH ROLLUP;
```

(In your case, this will show subtotals for each username, and a total for all results).

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Eggyal's answer with rollup, you could simplify yours by summing with your IF() as

```
SELECT 
      username,
      DATE(enddt) AS enddt,
      SUM( IF(duration <=30, 1,0 )) as 0To30,
      SUM( IF(duration BETWEEN 31 AND 60, 1,0 )) as 31To60,
      SUM( IF(duration BETWEEN 61 AND 120,1,0 )) as 61To120,
      SUM( IF(duration BETWEEN 121 AND 240,1,0 )) as 121To240,
      SUM( IF(duration >240,1,0)) as '>240'
   FROM 
      report
   GROUP BY 
      username,
      DATE(enddt)
   WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: SELECT username,COUNT(DISTINCT tickid) AS NewTick,COUNT(tickid)-COUNT(DISTINCT tickid) AS ReopenedTick,
      SUM( IF(duration <=30, 1,0 )) AS 0To30,
      SUM( IF(duration BETWEEN 31 AND 60, 1,0 )) AS 31To60,
      SUM( IF(duration BETWEEN 61 AND 120,1,0 )) AS 61To120,
      SUM( IF(duration BETWEEN 121 AND 240,1,0 )) AS 121To240,
      SUM( IF(duration >240,1,0)) AS '>240'
   FROM report WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND deptid=1
   GROUP BY username WITH ROLLUP;

Comment: @suresh, you posted a query as a comment.  You could always re-edit your post and add to that.  What is up with the query you posted.. other than you now appear to be recomputig a tickID basis.